# Atualizar p:selectonemenu primefaces

Tags: ajax, primefaces

Me deparei com um problema que não consegui solucionar.
Tenho um p:selectonemenu que tem um p:ajax com event change. Ao mudar o valor dele ele executa um listener que seta os valores de outros p:selectonemenu.
Ao dar o render do f:ajax ele não esta mostrando os valores dos outros p:selectonemenu, mesmo ja existindo os converters para as respectivas classes. Verificando no backbean o value atribuido aos p:selectonemenu estão com os valores corretos, apenas não aparece na tela. Quando executa qualquer validação aí sim os valores aparecem na tela.
[image: Imagem 1]
[image: Imagem 2]
[image: Imagem 3]

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver após muito tentar.
Troquei isso :

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{carregaDadosProduto()}" update="@form" />
```

por isso:

```
<p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="#{carregaDadosProduto()}" update="@form" />
```